# Time-series analysis in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I've a table containing four fields, an unique int id, a timestamp, a value and a int foreign key. Each record corresponds to a sensor measurement. What I'd like to do is create a new table, based on this with value replaced by the time since the previous timestamp of that foreign key (each FK being a different sensor).

I presume I'd start by doing a group by FK and then sorting, but I'm a bit lost as to where to go from there.

Thanks for any help you can offer,
James

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your table definition? Your test case? Your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample.

```
create temp table measurements (ts timestamp, sensor int);

insert into measurements
values
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:00', 1),
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:01', 1),
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:02', 1),
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:03', 2),
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:04', 2),
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:05', 2),
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:06', 3),
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:07', 3),
 ('2014-01-01 00:00:08', 3)
;

select sensor,
       ts,
       lag(ts) over (partition by sensor order by ts asc) as previous_measurement,
       ts - lag(ts) over (partition by sensor order by ts asc) as time_since_previous_measurement
from measurements
;
```

Note that if you want to discard the samples where the time since last measurement is null (i.e. the first samples) you'll need to wrap that query in an extra query like `select * from (select sensor, lag() ...) t where t.previous_measurement is not null`.

Comment: Wow, thanks, never heard of the lag or over functions in postgress before, that's brilliant. Thanks, I know it was a fairly general question, but now you've given me a solution, and terms to google, from which I found this, which is expounds on your point, http://fmcgeough.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/window-functions-in-postgres-lag/  Thanks very much!